# If I try to activate Auto Response to a message received through WhatsApp, why does it not work?

Tags: whatsapp

```
package com.chatbot.io.lk;

import android.app.Notification;

import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;

import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;

import android.util.Log;

import android.app.RemoteInput;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Intent;

public class MyNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationListener";

    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Posted: " + sbn.getPackageName());

        // Check if the notification is from WhatsApp

        if (isWhatsAppNotification(sbn)) {

            // Extract message

            String message = extractMessage(sbn);

            // Display message

            showToast(message);

            // Send auto response

            sendAutoResponse(message, sbn);

        }

    }

    private boolean isWhatsAppNotification(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        return sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp");

    }

    private String extractMessage(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

        return extras.getString("android.text");

    }

    private void sendAutoResponse(String message, StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Sending Auto Response");

        showToast("Sending starting..... ");

        

        // Check if notification has a RemoteInput

        if (sbn.getNotification().actions != null) {

            for (Notification.Action action : sbn.getNotification().actions) {

                if (action.getRemoteInputs() != null) {

                    // Get RemoteInput and PendingIntent

                    RemoteInput remoteInput = action.getRemoteInputs()[0];

                    PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = action.actionIntent;

                    // Generate response based on message

                    String replyMessage = generateResponse(message);

                    // Create Bundle and send reply

                    Bundle resultBundle = new Bundle();

                    resultBundle.putString(remoteInput.getResultKey(), replyMessage);

                    try {

                        replyPendingIntent.send(this, 0, new Intent());

                        Log.d(TAG, "Auto response sent successfully");

                        showToast("Sending.. ");

                    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Error sending auto response", e);

                        showToast("Error send");

                    }

                    break;

                }

            }

        } else {

            Log.d(TAG, "No RemoteInput found in notification");

            showToast("Remote not");

        }

    }

    private void showToast(String message) {

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private String generateResponse(String message) {

        // Implement your logic for generating a response based on the message

        // This is just an example

        return "Hi there! I received your message: " + message;

    }

}
```

I tried to AutoReply to a message via WhatsApp but it doesn't actually work even though Toast and Log show it working.